# Decoding scuba dive computer log files

Tags: file-format, log-files

Does anyone know of any libraries that decode one or more of the multitude of different scuba dive computer log file formats?

- DAN DL7
- IRIS / DRAK
- Suunto
- Oceanlog
- Citizen
- ProDive
- NiTek Logic
- DCDS

Ideally I'm looking for code that'll run in .NET, but I'm willing to transcode from other languages if that's the only option.

Links to articles describing formats is appreciated as well.  Sample log files would be handy.

I'm considering creating an open source project for this if no such library already exists.  If you'd like to contribute, please mention so as a comment or in your answer.

Comment: I don't have any useful input here but I'm very interested in the outcome (and possibly contributing to the OSS project).  Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with this but Google turned up the library **[libdivecomputer](http://divesoftware.org/libdc/)**.

It supports a number of devices and platforms, and the library is LGPL licensed. However, not all brands you mention appear to be supported.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  So far it seems to be my best bet.

Comment: For reference, [this post on a Mono mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2010-June/045333.html) shows an example of integrating with the libdivecomputer DLL via interop.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try contacting the manufacturers to get the data. You might have better luck contacting the engineers specifically, if you can find them.

I don't know much about the industry, but I would suspect you can make a case for opening up their formats, because they are primarily hardware manufacturers.